# Override setContentOffset

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, overriding

is it allowed to override the setContentOffset method of an UIScrollView while subclassing?? Is this AppStore save?

sample:

```
-(void)setContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset {
    [super setContentOffset:contentOffset];
    NSLog(@"co: %@",NSStringFromCGPoint(contentOffset));

    if(_willScroll)
        [_svDelegate setContentOffset:CGPointMake(contentOffset.x, contentOffset.y *2)];
}
```

thanks,

Omid

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  Lots of iPhone programmers subclass `UIScrollView` and then replace or extend functionality of public API's like `setContentOffset`.

The only correction I would make for you is to use the correct API.  It's not:

`setContentOffset:`

but instead it's

[`setContentOffset: animated:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIScrollView/setContentOffset%3aanimated%3a)

(i.e. with an `animated` parameter -- Apple's documentation is linked for you there).

Comment: To be precise, `setContentOffset:` (setting the `contentOffset` property) calls `setContentOffset:animated:` with the second argument set to `NO`. That's why you need to override the latter.

Comment: Hi Michael, i tried overriding the `setContentOffset:animated:` but it is not working for me. I try to synchronize two UIScrollViews so wenn the user drags one UIScrollView I would like to move the second on also... and that works only with `setContentOffset:`

Comment: Well remember if you are overriding, you should subclass UIScrollView (let's call it `OmidScrollView`).  Then set the classname of the `UIScrollView` objects in your XIB to your new class of `OmidScrollView`.

Answer (score 0):

In general this is no Problem to override some of these methods. You only add behaviour. Apple only refers to Interface Usability and so on.

So if your App feels still the "Apple-Way" it is all ok. https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html